# Getting following HTTP Error 500.19 and error code : 0x80070021

Tags: asp.net

when am debugging WCF service got the below error? "HTTP Error 500.19 and error code: 0x80070021" Followed below steps to fix it. However, still it didn't work 1]Open server manager 2]Click on Add Roles and Features 3]Select Role-based or feature based installation 4]Select a server from the server pool 5]On right panel 6]Select radio button-> Web server (IIS)-> Application development-> Installed ASP.NET 3.5-> Installed ASP.NET 4.7

Answer (score 0):

I am using visual studio 2017

1]Updated visual studio installer
2]After installing .NET Framework 4.6.2 developer pack

Issue got resolved